# Does php have a way to stop the call chain if a null value is encoutered?

Tags: php, php-7.3

I would like to do `self::container()->get($path);` but `self::container()` can return `null`.

Is there a quicker way to avoid the `Call to a member function get() on null` error when chaining function calls and some could return null instead of an object ?

Is there a better way than the ugly workaround of mocking the expected object/member?

```
public static function getDependency($path) {
 return self::container() ??
  (new class{public function get($path){return null;}})->get($path);
}
```

---

What I am after is something like the [null-conditional member access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) (`?.`) in C#

Comment: You should use the word "chaining", rather than "concatenation", which is rather used for strings.

Comment: @PatrickAllaert fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PHP 8.0, you have [Nullsafe methods and properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.nullsafe) and you can do:

self::container()?->get($path);

Otherwise, you have the original answer below as it targeted PHP 7.3:

Short answer: no, there is no such thing in PHP 7.3.

I would avoid doing magic like the one you suggested.

Doing:

```
<?php
public static function getDependency($path) {
    $container = self::container();
    if ($container instanceof ContainerInterface) {
        return $container->get($path);
    }
}
```

would be easier to read/understand.

Now, regarding `null`, it has been described by its own creator (Tony Hoare) ["The Billion Dollar Mistake"](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/).

A better approach would be that `self::container()` would have as return type `ContainerInterface` without the possibility of being `null`. Trying to returning a `null`, it would throw a `TypeError`, which could potentially be caught. This way, the call to `->get()` would never happen as the exception would be thrown before.

Allowing `self::container()` to return something like `ContainerInterface|null` would result in **all callers** to implement a logic as the one you proposed which would also lead to (lot of) duplicated code.

For the very same reason, you would probably be safer to have a specific return type for your dependency:

```
<?php
public static function getServiceFoo($path): ServicFoo {
    $container = self::container();
    if (!$container instanceof ContainerInterface) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid container received");
    }

    return $container->get($path);
}
```

Otherwise you will be exposed to the same issue on `getServiceFoo()` that you already have on `self::container()`.

Answer (score 4):

With the upcoming PHP 8 the [nullsafe_operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator) will be implemented and will allow to circuit break a chain of calls if null is returned by one of them

```
   $result = $o->returnNull()?->doSomething()
   $results === null // True
```